# Is there a limitation in rows or colums in TableLayoutPanel (Visual Basic 2013)?

Tags: vb.net, limit, tablelayoutpanel

(Sorry for my English, I'm French)

I have a problem with a TableLayoutPanel in which I create > 400 rows (6 colums by row) with one Picturebox in the 5th column and text in the other.
Note that I use "SetRowSpan" on many rows when it's possible (same class of image).
When the problem occurs, the first row contains 343 other lines (so 343 pictureboxs)

All is good until the 239th row... there the image isn't well display (shrunk).
After this, even if the rows and columns are well painted there are empty (no text, no image).

May somebody help me, please ?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: ~32760 pixels. -- That's not really the way to setup a TLP Container.

Comment: It sounds like you're rather abusing a WinForms GUI but at least provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to test.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answers,

I use a TLP because I didn't found another Ctrl to do the job.

I display an array with text, picture and link on many rows, like a catalog

I analyze the data to build the TLP with 1 row by article, and where there are many pictures I do "RowSpan".

I use TLP because I don't know how can I do with another control (I tried "DataGridView" but it seemed to me more difficult to mix text + picture in the same row)

The full code is, I think, complex (read on web site, analyze and make of the TLP) and I should make the "minimal" reproducible example specifically.